# Run as a Windows account in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I need to move a Asp.Net Core Kestrel application to IIS. The Asp.Net core application uses many Integrated Security connection strings and also need to access many other resources. The account used to run the application has all the permissions.

Now I will need to host it in IIS. Is it a way to "run as" the Asp.Net core code as a different account instead of the system account "Domain\MachineName$"?

Comment: Assuming you have already set the app pool identity to the domain account?

Comment: No I haven't. How to set it up?

Comment: Yep, so when hosting in IIS, your application is going to run under the context of the identity associate to the app pool that the application runs under. Three things of interests here. 1. Integrated security connection string are going to be intercepted by IIS and they will use the app pool identity. Right click your site in IIS > manage web site > Advanced Settings. Here you can see the application pool. Then go under the Application Pools section and find it. Right click ? Settings > Modify the Identity entry to your domain account

Comment: How about the permissions to access shared folder, etc? Will it use the app pool identity too?

Comment: It will, so you need to pout that domain user in the IIS_IUSRS group on the machine

Comment: Finally, IF you have your application set to use anon Auth (before user is logged in) then click on your site in iis > select Authentication in right pane >right click Anon auth > Edit then flip that to use the app pool identity